# Issue about dapper

Tags: orm, dictionary, dapper

```
public class Profile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ExtraInfo Extra { get; set; }
}

public class Topic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int UID { get; set; }

    public int TestColum { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Profile Author { get; set; }

    public Attachment Attach { get; set; }
}
```

correct：

```
var list = conn.Query<Topic, Profile, Topic>(
            @"select top 3 
                T.ID,
                T.Title,
                T.CreateDate,
                P.Phone,
                P.Name
            from Topic as T
            inner join Profile P on T.UID = P.ID",
            (T, P) => { T.Author = P; return T; },
            null,
            null,
            true,
            "Phone");
```

throw a exception at SqlMapper.cs line 2177：

```
var list = conn.Query<Topic, Profile, Topic>(
            @"select top 3 
                T.ID,
                T.Title,
                T.CreateDate,
                P.Name,
                P.Phone
            from Topic as T
            inner join Profile P on T.UID = P.ID",
            (T, P) => { T.Author = P; return T; },
            null,
            null,
            true,
            "Name");
```

Now,i delete the Topic's property "Name",that will be correct.

I think the key is at SqlMapper.cs line 1153

```
int current = 0;
var splits = splitOn.Split(',').ToArray();
var splitIndex = 0;

Func<Type, int> nextSplit = type =>
{
    var currentSplit = splits[splitIndex].Trim();
    if (splits.Length > splitIndex + 1)
    {
        splitIndex++;
    }

    bool skipFirst = false;
    int startingPos = current + 1;
    // if our current type has the split, skip the first time you see it. 
    if (type != typeof(Object))
    {
        var props = DefaultTypeMap.GetSettableProps(type);
        var fields = DefaultTypeMap.GetSettableFields(type);

        foreach (var name in props.Select(p => p.Name).Concat(fields.Select(f => f.Name)))
        {
            if (string.Equals(name, currentSplit, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                skipFirst = true;
                startingPos = current;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    int pos;
    for (pos = startingPos; pos < reader.FieldCount; pos++)
    {
        // some people like ID some id ... assuming case insensitive splits for now
        if (splitOn == "*")
        {
            break;
        }
        if (string.Equals(reader.GetName(pos), currentSplit, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (skipFirst)
            {
                skipFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    current = pos;
    return pos;
};
```

> "if our current type has the split, skip the first time you see it. "

When "current type" have a property that name equal "split",but we didn't select this field from db,dapper will throw a exception.

This is a design issue, or I am not used correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, it does indeed look like this is a scenario that should be handled better; it would be worth logging this as a bug on the project site - as this is quite subtle, and deciding the right way to fix this requires some thought.

<s>It looks like it *should* work, and I'm having difficulty making it fail with the code you show - the following works fine (tested with the 1.13 codebase):</s>

```
public void TestSplitWithMissingMembers()
{
    var result = connection.Query<Topic, Profile, Topic>(
    @"select 123 as ID, 'abc' as Title,
             cast('01 Feb 2013' as datetime) as CreateDate,
             'def' as Phone, 'ghi' as Name",
    (T, P) => { T.Author = P; return T; },
    splitOn: "Phone").Single();

    result.ID.Equals(123);
    result.Title.Equals("abc");
    result.CreateDate.Equals(new DateTime(2013, 2, 1));
    result.Name.IsNull();
    result.Content.IsNull();

    result.Author.Phone.Equals("def");
    result.Author.Name.Equals("ghi");
    result.Author.ID.Equals(0);
    result.Author.Address.IsNull();
}
```

Note I added:

```
public Profile Author { get; set; }
```

to `Topic`, but otherwise the code is identical. Is there any chance the issue has changed between your *actual* code and your *example* code? Happy to investigate, but I need to know I'm looking at the right thing.

Comment: I edit the question already.You can look at the question again.

Comment: And you should't set splitOn to "Phone",you can test set it to "Name".If we only need the "Name" of Profile,you will see a exception.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem.  I'm assuming this was too subtle to fix? (probably shouldn't have mapped a type I didn't select, but the error message is completely inconsistent with what the actual issue was)

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problem when you split by "Phone" is you should select P.Phone first:

```
 @"select top 3 
                T.ID,
                T.Title,
                T.CreateDate,
                P.Phone,
                P.Name

            from Topic as T
            inner join Profile P on T.UID = P.ID",
```